# Light fixture wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

I might be a bit paranoid but it's electricity!
I removed an older light fixture from my kitchen ceiling and am ready to attach the new one (Ikea)[image]. I just want to make sure that I am doing it correctly. I am assuming that it's from the house connect the copper wire to the green, the black to the black and the white to the white. If I sound dumb, that's ok, I'm new to this and like to err on the side of caution!

Comment: Yes, that'd correct.

Comment: I would remount the bar hanger so the screws that are attached to the box are equally spaced.  This will help avoid any installation hiccups and might cover the existing hole better.

Comment: There are no dumb questions when it comes to electricity. If you were not sure and willing to ask that makes you a smart person. If you're unsure of what are you doing or feel very uncomfortable with it always hire a professional. It's just not worth the risk.

Answer (score 5):

The green wire coming out of the new fixture, should be connected to the bare copper wire from the ceiling.  There should also be a pigtail from that connection, that connects to the green grounding screw on the strap (metal bit attached to the box).

Then it *should* be black to black, and white to white. For future reference, you should take photos, draw a diagram, or simply list/label all the wires when you disconnect them from fixtures before you remove them. That way you'll know how it was wired, and can wire it back up the same way.